# Pandas Dataframe Merging

Tags: pandas, merge

I have a bit of a weird pandas question.

I have a master Dataframe:

```
   a   b   c
0  22  44  55
1  22  45  22
2  44  23  56
3  45  22  33
```

I then have a dataframe in a different dimension which has some over lapping index's and column names

```
index   col_name  new_value
0        a          111 
3        b          234
```

I'm trying to then say if you find a match on index and col_name in the master dataframe, then replace the value.

So the output would be

```
   a   b   c
0  111  44  55
1  22  45  22
2  44  23  56
3  45  234  33
```

I've found "Combine_first" but this doesn't work unless I pivot the second dataframe (which I can't do in this scenario)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is `update` problem

```
df.update(updated.pivot(*updated.columns))
df
Out[479]: 
       a      b   c
0  111.0   44.0  55
1   22.0   45.0  22
2   44.0   23.0  56
3   45.0  234.0  33
```

Or

```
df.values[updated['index'].values,df.columns.get_indexer(updated.col_name)]=updated.new_value.values
df
Out[495]: 
     a    b   c
0  111   44  55
1   22   45  22
2   44   23  56
3   45  234  33
```

Comment: Thank you. My fault for not labelling but in your example is df the master dataframe and updated the one to add on?

Comment: @fred.schwartz yes , it is

Comment: And yes, using @W-B's method of pivoting `dim.pivot(*dim.columns).combine_first(master)` works.

Comment: @coldspeed thank you so much ! Without your support, this would not have been possible!